# Prevent access to an instance variable from subclass, without affecting base class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance

Say I have a simple class `Foo`, which comes from an external library, thus I cannot change it directly:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

I want to create a subclass `Bar` and prevent `x` from being change from an instance of `Bar`, but still use the `x` in `Bar`'s methods.

Here's what I tried, and it will probably enlighten the basic idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError('Do not change x directly, use "do_stuff()" instead')

    def do_stuff(self, value):
        if <something>:
            super().x = value
```

So basically I've created some wrapper functions (`do_stuff()`) around an attribute, and now I want to prevent the attribute from being changed directly, as it might mess up some functionality of the wrapper functions. Is this possible in a reasonable way?

**Edited** with a better example of what I want. I'm not trying to prevent them from seeing the variable `x`, but instead changing it from outside of `do_stuff()`

Comment: So you don't want to access the variable directly but want to use in functions. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @udhy Yes, exactly. I want to prevent *others* from accessing the attribute after they've instantiated `Bar`. So when someone does `bar = Bar(4); bar.x = 5` it will raise an error and tell them to use `do_stuff()` instead.

Comment: `Foo.__init__` has the same access to `x` everything else does. Unless you explicitly check *how* `x` is being assigned, e.g. with `inspect`, I don't see how you can do this. We're all consenting adults, so locking stuff down like this isn't really supported.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess that's one "No" to my "Is this possible in a reasonable way?". Too bad, although I didn't really think it would be possible. Still, worth asking!

Comment: Check this- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Comment: You could use `__setattr__` and some sort of flag to say whether or not you're currently allowed to set `x`, but that seems very fussy!

Comment: @CrakC What about it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That could work... In the `Bar.__init__`, after calling `super().__init__()`, I would change the `__setattr__` method of the instance, right? **Edit:** No that still wouldn't do, I can't change it afterwards in `do_stuff()`, and the parent class can't change it either...

Comment: You could implement `__init__`, set a flag (`self._can_set_x`?) before calling `super().__init__` and unset it afterwards, and check for that flag in `__setattr__`. Again, though, it's very fussy. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to prevent people from accessing the `move_type` attribute through my [EasyPlayer](https://github.com/MarkusMeskanen/EasyPlayer)  class. It should be enough information if you read the `README.md`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be much simpler to accomplish if you are willing to avoid inheritance altogether:

```
def main():
    bar = Bar(123)
    bar.fizz()
    bar.buzz()
    bar.fizz()
    bar.set_x(456)
    print('bar.x =', bar.x)
    try:
        bar.x = 123
    except AttributeError:
        print('bar.x cannot be set directly')
    else:
        raise AssertionError('an AttributeError should have been raised')
    bar.mutate_x(789)
    bar.fizz()
    bar.set_x(0)
    bar.fizz()
    bar.mutate_x(1)
    bar.fizz()
    bar.set_x('Hello World')
    bar.fizz()


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def fizz(self):
        print(self.x)

    def buzz(self):
        self.x = None


class Bar:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__foo = foo = Foo(x)
        self.__copy_methods(foo)

    def __copy_methods(self, obj):
        for name in dir(obj):
            if name.startswith('__') or name.endswith('__'):
                continue
            attr = getattr(obj, name)
            if callable(attr):
                setattr(self, name, attr)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__foo.x

    def set_x(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int) and value > 0:
            self.__foo.x = value

    mutate_x = set_x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is a working solution, but the original `Foo` class is way more complicated than I've let you guys know. It has a custom metaclass and a long inheritance tree above it. I will not go this route yet (if ever), but it's a working solution and I'll keep it in mind if I don't come up with anything else! Thank you for the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No, this is not possible in a **reasonable** way.

Python's guiding principle here, to use the phrasing from the [style guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users) is that we are all responsible users. Meaning that code is trusted not to do silly things, and people should generally avoid messing with members of other people's classes without a good reason.

The first and best way to prevent people from accidentally changing a value is to mark it using the single underscore (`_variable`). This however may not offer you the protection you want against accidental modification of your variables.

The next step up in protection is to use a double underscore. Quoting from [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables):

> To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules.
>
> Python mangles these names with the class name: if class Foo has an attribute named __a , it cannot be accessed by Foo.__a . (An insistent user could still gain access by calling Foo._Foo__a .) **Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.**

The mangling makes it more difficult to accidentally overwrite a value.

I added emphasis to that last sentence because it is important. Using this mechanism for preventing accidental access to a member is not really the something that should be done for a lot of members.

In your specific case, the way that I'd solve the problem would be to not subclass at all.  Consider:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._foo = Foo(x)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._foo.x

    def do_stuff(self, value):
        # Validate the value, and the wrapped object's state
        if valid:
            self._foo.x = value
```

Of course this means that `Bar` has to wrap all of `Foo`'s methods that you want to wrap. Yes, someone could still,

```
b = Bar(100)
b._foo.x = 127 # shame on them :)
```

or

```
b = Bar(100)
b._foo = EvilFoo(127)
```

but it's harder to unintentionally do.

Comment: The first part of your answer is quite irrelevant (well, at least useless to **me**) since, unfortunately, I cannot change how the original base class `Foo` names its variables. I already replied to @NoctisSkytower about the same suggestion you made (not using inheritance): "This is a working solution, but the original Foo class is way more complicated than I've let you guys know. It has a custom metaclass and a long inheritance tree above it. I will not go this route yet (if ever), but it's a working solution and I'll keep it in mind if I don't come up with anything else!"

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you want to make `x` a property instead of having it be an attribute in the subclass. Where you went wrong was trying to store the raw data for `x` on super. What you want to do is exploit the fact that the parent class can use the new property of the subclass transparently and does not need to know that it is now a property and not a attribute. Something like this should work for you:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar(Foo):

    _protected_x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._protected_x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if self._protected_x is None:
            self._protected_x = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Use set_x to change x.")

    def set_x(self, value):
        self._protected_x = value

b = Bar(12)
print b.x
b.set_x(5)
print b.x
```